# Provisioning Web Apps for office365

Tags: api, powershell, office365

How can we Provisioning Web Apps and its functionality for Office 365. I couldn't find any powershell cmdlets or api provided by microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Web Apps"? Do you mean SharePoint Web Applications? If so, an Office 365 Tenant can only have the one default SharePoint Web Application, but it can have multiple site collections that you can create using the CSOM APIs. We actually demoed the usage of this API at TechEd NA 2014 and the recording can be found here http://channel9.msdn.com/events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B390#fbid=FvODt5WoCtN